# How to prepend all filenames on the list with common path?

Tags: cmake, path, filenames, cmake-scopes

How can I prepend all filenames on the list with a common path prefix automatically? For instance having a list of files in CMakeLists.txt:

```
SET(SRC_FILES foo1.cpp foo2.cpp)
```

I'd like to get a list that is equivalent to this:

```
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo1.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo2.cpp
```

I need this to use filenames in a PARENT_SCOPE context, e.g.

```
SET(FILES_TO_TRANSLATE ${FILES_TO_TRANSLATE} ${SRC_FILES} PARENT_SCOPE)
```

so, that a CMakeFiles.txt in another directory can still find these files.

In essence, I'd expect something like this (pseudo-code):

```
SET(FILES_TO_TRANSLATE PREPEND_ALL_NAMES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${SRC_FILES}) PARENT_SCOPE)
```

Is this is easily doable, or do I have to user "foreach" loop to create new list of files?

Answer (score 65):

CMake 3.12 added list transformers - one of these transformers is `PREPEND`. Thus, the following can be used inline to prepend all entries in a list:

`list(TRANSFORM FILES_TO_TRANSLATE PREPEND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})`

...where `FILES_TO_TRANSLATE` is the variable name of the list.

More information can be found in the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/list.html).

Comment: If you use this, make sure you add `cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.12 )` in your CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: I can't get this working: with `set(A "thing"), list(TRANSFORM ${A} PREPEND "some")` the content of A is still "thing". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to reference the list by its name only (e.g. just plain `A` instead of `${A}`)

Comment: And now version 3.15 even [added the `list(PREPEND ...)` command directly](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html#prepend).

Comment: @ComicSansMS `list(PREPEND ...)`, according to the doc you linked, *inserts elements to the 0th position in the list*. This does not achieve prepending something to each item.

Comment: @flyx Oh, you're right, of course. My bad, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 34):

Following function may be what you want.

```
FUNCTION(PREPEND var prefix)
   SET(listVar "")
   FOREACH(f ${ARGN})
      LIST(APPEND listVar "${prefix}/${f}")
   ENDFOREACH(f)
   SET(${var} "${listVar}" PARENT_SCOPE)
ENDFUNCTION(PREPEND)
```

To use it,

```
PREPEND(FILES_TO_TRANSLATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${SRC_FILES})
```

Comment: Even though this works,  the function declaration is misleading since it only lists 2 function arguments var, prefix. However in practice the user has to pass ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${SRC_FILES} as the prefix argument.

Comment: It is true that it requires the third parameter. However, you need to add the third argument to the front of the FOREACH list.

Comment: What is "FILES_TO_TRANSLATE"?

Comment: `FILES_TO_TRANSLATE` is just a CMake variable that stores the list of the file, same with what OP used.

Comment: Does new versions of cmake have a similar (but official) function ?

Comment: Can I update the list inplace without creating a new copy?

Answer (score 17):

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "([^;]+)" "ANYPREFIX/\\1.cpp" outputlist "${inputlist}")
```

Replace ANYPREFIX with any prefix and '.cpp' with any suffix you need.

Comment: This is a great answer actually. You may want to preprocess your list to remove the original extension (if that's what you're doing):

string(REPLACE ".json" "" inputlist "${inputlist}")

Comment: what does `;` means in your regular expression.

Comment: in cmake list is just a string with semicolon-separated strings, so you can just apply regex or any other string operation to it as a string and be done with it. ([^;]+) mean to "take all characters till next ';'"

Comment: "Huh, a regex. Bet it's wrong." Yep. Files containing `;` won't work properly. Better to let CMake look through the list - it handles things correctly.

Comment: My bet that most regex haters just don't know how to use them properly. Creating file names with semicolon in cmake is shooting yourself in the leg. And cmake doesn't support such file names. Run `cmake --help-policy CMP0037` for more information.

Comment: Why "1.cpp"? What does that mean?

Comment: It is not 1.cpp, it is \\1 AND .cpp.

Comment: Why are you adding an extra `.cpp`?

Comment: That just an example of how to add both prefix and postfix. Edited answer to make that clear.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a `foreach` loop. But if you use that in several parts of your project, you might want to create a function or a macro.

Answer (score 3):

As an improvement to Ding-Yi Chen's answer, if you still need to support pre-3.12 CMake as I do, you can use following code:

```
function(list_transform_prepend var prefix)
    set(temp "")
    foreach(f ${${var}})
        list(APPEND temp "${prefix}${f}")
    endforeach()
    set(${var} "${temp}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

Advantage of this solution is, that interface is closer to one is CMake 3.12 `list(TRANSFORM ...)` and the change is done in-place.

Used like this

```
list_transform_prepend(FILES_TO_TRANSLATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/")
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want an absolute filename as you are prepending ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}. If you are using `FILE(GLOB <VAR> <PATTER>)`, all the files will have an absolute path already:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_FILES src/*.cpp)
```

See the [comments CMake in documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3afile) on why not to use GLOB to add source files.