# CMake - input does not change inside function

Tags: list, function, cmake

I am trying to write a function in CMake which will take a list, and update it such that each item in the list is prepended with an additional string.

My code is along the lines of the following (roughly based on an answer to a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346412/how-to-prepend-all-filenames-on-the-list-with-common-path#27630120)):

```
function(prepend_number _input_list)
    set(_new_list "")
    foreach(_item ${_input_list})
        list(APPEND _new_list "number_${_item}")
    endforeach()

    message(STATUS "Input: ${_input_list}")
    message(STATUS "Ammended list: ${_new_list}")

    set(${_input_list} "${_new_list}" PARENT_SCOPE)
    message(STATUS "Revised input: ${_input_list}")
endfunction() 

set(numbers one two three four five)

prepend_number("${numbers}")
```

From this I get the following output:

```
Input: one;two;three;four;five
Ammended list: number_one;number_two;number_three;number_four;number_five
Output: one;two;three;four;five
```

I am confused by this. Why does the value of `_input_list` not equate to that of `_new_list`?

If I add an extra line of code to display the contents of numbers outside of the function (i.e. `message(STATUS "${numbers}")`) I get a similar result, the contents of `numbers` has not changed. What is missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider these two lines:

```
set(${_input_list} "${_new_list}" PARENT_SCOPE)
message(STATUS "Revised input: ${_input_list}")
```

`${_input_list}` is being replaced with its value. What `set` command does here is creating variable `one` in parent scope, since `one` is the first element of `_input_list`.

In order to modify the original list, you need to pass its name, not value:

```
function(prepend_number _list_var)

    foreach(_item ${${_list_var}})
        list(APPEND _new_list "number_${_item}")
    endforeach()

    message(STATUS "Input var: ${_list_var}")
    message(STATUS "Input: ${${_list_var}}")

    set(${_list_var} "${_new_list}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction() 

set(numbers one two three four five)

set(numbers "5" "6" "7")
prepend_number(numbers)
message(STATUS "${numbers}")
```

Note that `_list_var` above is a string containing the name of the original variable, not its value. For this reason, I'm using `${${_list_var}}` syntax to access elements.

For the same reason, when calling `prepend_numbers`, I'm passing `numbers` instead of `${numbers}`.

String typing at its worst :(

Comment: This is really helpful, thank-you! I kept seeing the ${${variable}} notation previously and thinking I was missing something, now I understand why.